# rails partial passing param got empty variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I try to pass a param to a partial in view

**controller**

```
def addMovie
  @movies = Movie.all
  @vid = Movie.new
end
```

**view**

```
<%= render partial: "shared/videoList", videoList: :movies %>
```

**partial**
stored in app/views/sharead

```
<% if @videoList.present? %>
    <% @videoList.each do |movie| %>
```

videoList is empty ... why?

Comment: try render 'shared/videoList', :locals => { videoList: @movies}

Comment: problem is that '@movies' is empty. ... I tried <%= Movie.all.inspect %> in view ... works fine ... but the @movies is empty ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access the variable using `videoList` and not `@videoList`,

```
<% if videoList.present? %>
    <% videoList.each do |movie| %>
```

also, you need to pass the variable like this

```
<%= render 'shared/videoList', videoList: @movies %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks. but then I got this error: 'undefined local variable or method `videoList' for'

Comment: but in database there are entries

Comment: Check if the `@movies` variable is empty or not!

Comment: problem is that '@movies' is empty. ... I tried <%= Movie.all.inspect %> in view ... works fine ... but the @movies is empty ...